# Maintaining correct order when transferring records with Data Flow Tasks into a DB table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the following problem with a Sequence Container in an SSIS package in SQL Server 2008. In the container I have around 50 data flow tasks, which all transfer data from text files to one table in the SQL database. Every text file has the same construction so the data flow is identical. I have set it up for each transfer to happen one after the other. However, after running the transfer now, the top line is line 1774 from the 39th table to be transferred! How can I make it keep the records in the destination table in exactly the same order that they were transferred?

Comment: Does the destination table have an IDENTITY column?   What do you mean that "the top line is [xxx]"?   Tables don't have a "top line".

Comment: Nothing guarantees order of records on a query if no Order by was used.

Comment: At the moment the destination table does not have an identity column. By top line, I mean the first row in the text table (which I am transferring from).

Answer (score 0):

With each file in a different Data Flow Task you can use precedence constraints to make each file process in a specific order, but that will have a performance impact.

As far as controlling the order that individual rows are inserted, however, I think you're out of luck.  Remember that, by design, the order of rows in a table is not guaranteed.  AFAIK, even in SQL Server with clustered indexes they say that any order in a query's result set should be considered coincidental without an ORDER BY.  If you need a specific order, you should have a field from your data file and in your table which determines that order, such as a date, sequence number, or other sortable field.  That way your queries are data-driven, and not implementation-driven.

See also: [Retain The Order while Insert Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925391/retain-the-order-while-insert-rows)

As that says, for the most part you can get reasonably close with IDENTITY columns, but if you're looking for *guarantees*, there aren't any.  The order of rows is defined to be not relevant until you create fields or tables that define that relationship.  That's part of how an RDBMS works.

If you absolutely, positively have to control order of insertion (e.g., because the application requires it and it is out of your control), I think you'll probably need to write your own program or script which opens each file in sequence, opens a connection with the SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level, and then inserts each row in their own transaction one at a time, commits the transaction, and then moves to the next row.  This will be about as slow as it's possible to be, however, since it has a lot of database overhead.

Even then, you're only controlling the order the rows are inserted, and not the order the rows are physically stored in the database.  The best control you can get over that is clustered key, and as I said that's partly an implementation driven coincidence.

Comment: i would agree with you, however i think the OP is not using an ORDER BY clause in his query when checking.  Thus, I think what Ala is saying is correct.

Comment: @Greg That's possible.  I was answering with the impression that there was no field that could accurately reproduce the desired order at all.  I thought it was more likely that that was the case than that they simply didn't specify an ORDER BY clause.  Also, I wanted to answer the question as it was asked.

Comment: You are right - I don't have an Order By clause. Tbh I don't know how to include such a clause when the data source is a text file. I am learning by doing here and would welcome someone explaining to me how to do that. Where/How do I see the SQL with the data source "text file"? By the way the reason I need to keep the order correct is that the first three columns have blanks in them and I have to fill up the values from the last given value. Obviously this doesn't work if the rows are jumbled up.

Comment: @KristinaAleshnikova You're going to need to post some example data, explain how you need to modify the data (with examples) and explain why you think you need to maintain row order.  Whatever the problem you're trying to solve is, you're probably [going about it the wrong way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The point of my answer was, "You can try to do that, but it's probably not useful."  Go back a step and describe what you're *actually* trying to do.